# jQuery Mobile SimpleDialog with two Inputs?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am using the jQuery Mobile SimpleDialog (http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/) on a mobile site and I don't quite understand how I could go about implementing it with multiple inputs.

Currently I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // $('#createlocation').remove();
        });
        $(document).delegate('#searchdialog', 'click', function() {
          $('<div>').simpledialog2({
            mode: 'button',
            headerText: 'Route Search',
            headerClose: true,
            buttonPrompt: 'Enter your search:',
            buttonInput: true,
            buttons : {
              'OK': {
                click: function () { 
                  alert($.mobile.sdLastInput);
                }
              },
            }
          })
        });
    </script>
```

Which is just called from a button click as follows:

```
<a href="#page1" id="searchdialog" data-theme="" data-icon="search">
                            Search Routes
                        </a>
```

So instead of having just one input, how could I have two?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **mode:'button'** use [**mode:'blank'**](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/blank.html)

Then you can put whatever you like into **blankcontent** - as many inputs as you want.