# how to create two text boxes using simpledialog in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have seen the below link but it is not working for me.
[jQuery Mobile SimpleDialog with two Inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275319/jquery-mobile-simpledialog-with-two-inputs)

can anyone help me by seeing the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).delegate('#addDialog', 'click', function() {
                $(this).simpledialog({
                    'mode' : 'string',
                    'prompt' : 'Product',
                    'cleanOnClose': true,
                    'buttons' : {
                        'OK': {
                            click: function () { 
                                $('#simplestringout').text($('#addDialog').attr('data-string'));
                            }
                        },
                        'Cancel': {
                            click: function () { console.log(this); },
                            icon: "delete",
                            theme: "c"
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
```

I am calling this function by clicking on button.

Here I am getting perfectly as 1 text box. But when I want two text fileds I am unable to get it.

Can anyone please help me in how to get two text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to get 2 inputs you need to use blank mode and create the dialog markup you want.

Here is an example where the blankContent attribute is used to inject markup with 2 inputs and 2 buttons into the dialog. Then a handler is added for the OK button using event delegation (.on()) because the button does not exist until the dialog is launched:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#openDialog", function () {
        $('<div>').simpledialog2({
            mode: 'blank',
            headerText: 'Product',
            headerClose: true,
            width: "75%",
            blankContent: '<div class="sdCont"><label for="inp1">Text input 1:</label><input id="inp1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Type something..." /><label for="inp2">Text input 2:</label><input id="inp2" type="text" value="" placeholder="Really, go ahead and type..." /><div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><button id="btnOK" data-inline->OK</button></div><div class="ui-block-b"><button id="btnCancel" data-theme="c" data-icon="delete" rel="close">Cancel</button></div></div></div>'
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#btnOK", function(){
        alert("Dialog OK clicked!");
        $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.close();
    });
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hccYK/)**

Comment: Hi Ezanker, I tried to modified the version in jsfiddle. But it is not working for other versions. When I use your code it is not working fine.

Comment: Hi Ezanker, Please check the below plugin's I am using. Let me know if there are any corrections. <pre> <code> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="simpledialog.css" type="text/css" />
  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="simpledialog.js"></script> </pre> </code>

Comment: Your code is placed in script and click functionality made it as <pre><code><a href="" data-icon="plus" id="openDialog" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade"></a></code></pre>